# Spark: explode 1 row into many rows?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

for example:
mydataframe has 2 columns and 1 row

```
val df = Seq(("1,2,3", "tom")).toDF("id", "name")


ids(String)           name(String)

1,2,3         tom
```

after transform =>

I want the df to be equal to

```
Seq(("1", "tom"), ("2", "tom"), ("3", "tom")).toDF("id", "name")

ids  name

1     tom

2     tom

3     tom
```

I saw there is an explode() function with the following signiture:

```
public <A extends scala.Product> DataFrame explode(scala.collection.Seq<Column> input,
                                      scala.Function1<Row,scala.collection.TraversableOnce<A>> f,
                                      scala.reflect.api.TypeTags.TypeTag<A> evidence$1)
```

1. I want to use scala API

Comment: Give more explanation about your problem

Comment: You also need to describe what API you're using; Spark can be in Scala, Python or R.  And it would help to show some code you tried.

Comment: Please provide the DataFrame schema along with the API that you want to use

Comment: I updated problem description

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
df.select(explode(df.ids).alias('ids'), name).collect()
```